# Iron:Router url parameter to modify nested layout

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm really struggling with this one. If you want to view what I have bludgeoned together, it is all in a [repo on GitHub called instructor-oracle](https://github.com/knu2xs/instructor-oracle). What I would like to do is have the landing page be the layout at `./wbs`. Then I would like the search to route to `./wbs/:_wbsCode` and populate the sidebar with the appropriate record. I am thinking the router needs to be structured something like...

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function () {

    this.route('wbs', {
        path: '/wbs'
    }, function () {
        this.render('wbs-detail', {
            path: '/wbs/:_wbsAbbrev',
            to: 'wbs-detail',
            data: function () {
                theOne = Wbs.findOne({abbrev: this.params._wbsAbbrev});
                console.log(theOne.abbrev);
                return theOne;
            }
        });
    });
```

...and this would be paried with templates like...

```
<template name="layout">
    <header class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{pathFor 'wbs'}}">Instructor Oracle</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" id="wbsSearchForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                            class="form-control typeahead"
                            name="wbsSearch"
                            id="wbsSearch"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Search"
                            autocomplete="on"
                            spellcheck="off"
                            autofocus="true"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Find</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="container-fluid">
        {{> yield}}
    </main>
</template>

<template name="wbs">
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="wbsCol">
        {{> yield 'wbs-detail'}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9" id="timesheetCol">
        <iframe src="http://iframeurl.html" id="timesheetFrame"></iframe>
    </div>
    {{#contentFor 'wbs-detail'}}
        <h1>{{abbrev}} <small>{{code}}</small></h1>
    {{/contentFor}}
</template>
```

...and an event handler for the form like this...

```
Template.layout.events({

    // catch submit event for wbs form
    'submit': function (event, template) {

        // prevent default behavior and stop bubbling
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        // store dom element in variable
        var inputElement = template.find('input#wbsSearch');

        // access value in form and extract abbreviation if found
        var abbrev = Wbs.findOne({abbrev: (inputElement.value).toUpperCase()}).abbrev;

        // clear input
        inputElement.value = "";

        // go to the page
        Router.go('wbs-edit', {_wbsAbbrev: abbrev});
    }
});
```

I have been trying to sort through this on the iron:router documentation, but right now I am all kinds of lost (obviously). Still, I need this to work to avoid reloads on the main layout template so the iframe does not reload while the sidebar can change along with the matching url so links to specific sidebar content can be bookmarked and shared.

Thank you in advance for your assistance. If I eventually sort all of this out, I am more than happy to contribute to the iron:router documentation so it makes sense for the next pea-brained idiot like myself who happens to need to sort this out.

Comment: Hunch: [`{{> Template.dynamic }}`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_dynamic) ?

Comment: I eventually wound up not being able to use the path for each returned value from the search, instead using a session variable. This was kind of a silver bullet problem. Goodbye Meteor. It is back to MongoDB + Mongoose + Node.js + Express + Ember.js.

Comment: Fair enough. Have you asked on [iron-router's GitHub](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues)?